# Mediawiki interwiki 'what links here'

Tags: php, mediawiki

how can I write a MediaWiki extension and/or template that transcludes into page X of wiki A all references made to A:X in another wiki, like a page in French wikipedia being able to display a list with all references made to it in the English version?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and guidance.

---

In addition to the above, I checked MW API docs and found that query action has a iwbacklink value that lists all interwiki backlinks. This query returns a XML file with a list of all links in A that point to page X:

```
wikiA.com/api.php?action=query&list=iwbacklinks&blimit=50&blnamespace=0&bltitle=MY_PAGE_X
```

while this returns one the same data but as JSON:

```
wikiA.com/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=iwbacklinks&blimit=50&blnamespace=0&bltitle=MY_PAGE_X
```

Before either output can be presented on Wiki B it has to be parsed and formatted, which is easy to do in PHP. All I need now is to figure out how to include the output of a php script into a MW page. The overall result should be like this:

### LOREM IPSUM

Lorem Ipsum camem latina est quod usata ad interetem paginam sub constructa.

### List of pages in Wiki A that link to this page:

1) Camina Burana
2) Catilinaria
3) De Bellum Gallum

My intention of course is that the subsection should be created automatically whenver the page is called.

I thank both mario and svick for their suggestions and would welcome others.

Comment: It works on WikiPedia because all languages share a database set. For noting remote wiki links, you'll have to resort to scraping or logging Referers. There didn't emerge a common API for exchanging backlinks among the various wiki engines.

Comment: @mario It does work on Wikipedia? Do you have a link? I don't know about any tool that would track links between different projects.

Comment: @svick: Try http://toolserver.org/~merl/reverselanglinks/ for an external tool. Also, since WikiData interwikilinks are shared between the wikis and can be tracked easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, yet: it's an open feature request. Please subscribe on the issue tracker or submit patches. https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T3886